# can not decode html entities on php page from sql database

Tags: php, mysql, html-encode

I have a mysql database that records some text, with special chars encoded. example

```
he is called &quot;mike&quot;
```

then when i tried to decode in to display in my php page, but it does not work. sample code:

```
echo' <p class="secr_texto">'.htmlspecialchars_decode($reg2['text']).'</p>';
```

i get the encoded html only.
the page is utf-8 encoded and database too.

How do i get the decoded entities?

Comment: It might be your browser, try using another one

Comment: Thanks for the status report? Did you have a question? [http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htmlspecialchars has a flag you can use for quotes, otherwise it ignores it
`ENT_QUOTES`

```
echo' <p class="secr_texto">'.htmlspecialchars_decode($reg2['text'], ENT_QUOTES).'</p>';
```

so try that.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any function to encode those special characters. When you insert it into database and fetch in page Then it is automatically encoded.